# I need to compare the data in rows of a html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs, html-table

I am using a javascript loop to create a table made up of figures. The code currently creates the table fine and i have added some styles to it. 
The problem i am having is finding a way to compare the data within the cell columns in order to highlight the best and worst performer within that group for that column.

Here are the javascript functions i am using.

```
function performanceMetricsLoad() {
var records = storePerformanceMetricsData.getRecordsValues();
var groupTracker = null;
var assetTracker = null;
var htmlStr;
htmlStr = "<table class='TableStyles'><thead class='HeaderStyles'><tr><th width='400'>Name</th><th width='110'>1 month Cumulative Performance to "
            + records[0].DatetimeRecorded.format("F j, Y") + "</th><th width='110'>3 month Cumulative Performance to "
            + records[0].DatetimeRecorded.format("F j, Y") + "</th><th width='110'>6 month Cumulative Performance to "
            + records[0].DatetimeRecorded.format("F j, Y") + "</th><th width='110'>12 month Cumulative Performance to " 
            + records[0].DatetimeRecorded.format("F j, Y") + "</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {

    if (groupTracker != records[i].ClassOption) {
        htmlStr += "<tr>" + "<td class='GroupStyleCSS' colspan='5'>" 
        + records[i].Diversification + "</td></tr>";
        groupTracker = records[i].ClassOption;
    }

    if (groupTracker == records[i].ClassOption) {
        htmlStr += "<tr>" + "<td class='RecordCssStyle'>" + records[i].AssetLongName
        + "</td>"+ "<td class='RecDiv'>" + records[i].TotalReturn1m.toFixed(2)
        + "</td>" + "<td class='RecDiv'>" + records[i].TotalReturn3m.toFixed(2)
        + "</td>" + "<td class='RecDiv'>" + records[i].TotalReturn6m.toFixed(2) 
        + "</td>" + "<td class='RecDiv'>" + records[i].TotalReturn12m.toFixed(2) + "</tr>"; 
        assetTracker = records[i].AssetLongName;
    }
}

htmlStr += "</tbody></table>";
createRow("", htmlStr);
frmMetrics.doLayout();
```

}

```
function createRow(cls, text) {
frmMetrics.add(new Ext.BoxComponent({
    cls: cls,
    html: "<div>" + text + "</div>"
}));
```

}

the information is output into an EXT formPanel.

The problem i have is now i have it outputting the information i need to find a way to highlight the best and worst performers within the columns, within the groupings...

the table outputs 5 columns along the top, and up to 10 groups down the left hand side of fund names which are grouped by their 'diversification', depending on the information requested using an SQL query.

Does anybody have an idea of a way i could do this with the current state of this piece of code? i was thinking about using another external function and possibly some if statements selecting different css classes...any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Many thanks.

sorry for the lack of screenshots, i tried to include some but apparently i need a reputation score of 10 before i can, or something along those lines...

Comment: Isn't it programming 101 to find the largest and the smallest number? well you can create a variable for largest and smallest, and while creating each row, compare the value with the largest and the smallest. If it is larger than the largest change the largest variable and same with the smallest.

Comment: Definitely **do not** use the DOM for data storage. It's really slow. Do all your comparisons in JavaScript using JavaScript variables as you add the rows and add extra CSS classes to the ones that need it.

Comment: If you're already using Ext, I presume that you're at least somewhat happy with the Ext "look."  So, why not ditch the raw table and use the Ext.grid.Panel instead?  You could have it use a store that represents your performance metrics data structure.  Then you could use the Ext framework functionality (in a column renderer function, for example) to do your formatting.

Comment: I have been told explicitly that this function has not to use the EXT gridpanel, it would have been my first choice if this wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two lines to the top of your function

```
var largest;
var smallest;
```

Then in your loop, add:

```
if(value > largest){
    largest = value;
}
if(value < smallest){
    smallest = value;
}
```

If you want to add styles to the cells with those values add in a line to store the index of those values (updated in the same way) and set the  or  and select for the ID with css.